# How can I pass an input value to another component? I want to perform a global search

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, search

My structure is :
src/app/Home, src/app/Search , src/app/services/share-data-service.
I already tried some methods like passing the data from search using a service because I think there is no relation between the components, but it doesn't work .
This is also something that I tried https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khwjt3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Edit:
home.html:

```
     <head>
    <meta name="referrer" content="origin">
 
</head>

<body>
<!-- Toolbar -->
<div class="jumbotron" >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="w3-container"   >
        <!-- Highlight Card -->
 
        <section class="search-sec">
          <div class="container">
              <form action="#" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                          <div class="row">
                              <div  class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0 form-group">
                                  <input (input)="onInput($event)" type="text" name="city_search"  class="form-control search-slt" placeholder="Enter destination">
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0 form-group">
                                  <input  [(ngModel)]="nr_of_persons" name="nr_of_persons"   type="text" class="form-control search-slt" placeholder="Enter persons">
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0 form-group">
                                  <select  [(ngModel)]="type_of_vacation" name="type_of_vacation"  class="form-control search-slt" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" >
                                    <option value="Select type of vacation">Select type of vacation </option>
                                    <option value="City break">City break</option>
                                    <option value="Summer vacation">Summer vacation</option>
                                    <option value="Winter vacation">Winter vacation</option>
                                    <option value="Business vacation">Business vacation</option>
                                    <option value="Honeymoon">Honeymoon</option>
                                    <option value="Cruise">Cruise</option>
                                  </select>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                                  <button  type="button" style="background-color: #4eb478; border-color: seagreen;" class="btn btn-danger wrn-btn "  (click)="go()">Search</button>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div
```

home.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent  {
  

  registerForm: FormGroup;

  city_search:string;
  nr_of_persons:number;
  type_of_vacation:string;

  posts: Observable<Array<TripPayload>>;

  username:string;
  constructor(private store:Store, private sharedDataService:ShareDataService, private addPostService: AddPostService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient,private router:Router, public calendarService:CalendarService, public guestsService:GuestsService, private loginService:LoginService){
    this.registerForm=this.formBuilder.group( {username : '' });


  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.posts = this.addPostService.getAllPosts();
    
    this.username = this.loginService.getUserName();
    this.posts =this.addPostService.getRecommendations(this.username);
  }

search(){
  this.posts = this.addPostService.searchPost(this.nr_of_persons,this.city_search,this.type_of_vacation);
}

public onInput(event: any){
  // this pushes the input value into the service's Observable.
  this.sharedDataService.searchTerm.next(event.target.value);
}

public go(){
  window.location.href='../search';
}
}
```

share-data-service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShareDataService {
  public searchTerm: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
}
```

search.html:

```
      <head>
    <meta name="referrer" content="origin">
 
</head>

<body>
<!-- Toolbar -->
<div class="jumbotron" >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="w3-container"   >
        <h1>{{searchTerm}}</h1>
        <!-- Highlight Card -->
        <div  class="card-list" fxLayout="row wrap"  >
            <div  class="card" fxFlex="30%" *ngFor="let post of posts | async" style="margin:10px;" >
                <img src={{post.photoId}} alt="Cabana" style="width:100%">
                <h4><a href="/single-post/{{post.id}}"  class="post-title">{{post.title}}</a></h4>
                <div class="username-class">
                   <i class="fa fa-user"></i>Autor: {{post.username}}
                </div>
                <p [innerHTML]="post.content"></p>
                <div style="  clear: both;
                display: inline-block;
                overflow: hidden;">
                <div>
                    <div class="location">Tara: <p type="text">{{post.country }}</p></div>
                    <div class="location">Judet: <p type="text" >{{post.state}}</p></div>
                    <div class="location">Oras: <p type="text" >{{post.city}}</p></div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="check"><i  class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Check-In: <p type="date">{{post.check_in_date }}</p></div>
                    <div class="check"><i  class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Check-Out: <p type="date" >{{post.check_out_date}}</p></div>
                </div>
                    <i class="fa fa-money"></i>Pret: {{post.price}} EURO
                </div>
                <p><button><div class="star-rating-container star-rating-animation" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" >

                    <div *ngFor="let star of stars" [ngClass]="[star.class]" (click)="selectStar(star.id,post.id,post.username)">
                        <mat-icon>{{star.icon}}</mat-icon>
                    </div>
                
                </div></button></p>
            
                <div>
                    <a type="button" href="/single-post/{{post.id}}" class="read-more btn btn-default">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

search.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-results',
  
  templateUrl: './search-results.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-results.component.css'],
})
export class SearchResultsComponent {
  posts: Observable<Array<TripPayload>>;

  public city:string;
  nr_of_persons:number;
  type_of_vacation:string;
  public searchTerm: string = "";
  constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef,private sharedDataService: ShareDataService,public home:HomeComponent, private addPostService:AddPostService) { 

  
  }

  ngOnInit(){
      this.sharedDataService.searchTerm.subscribe((newValue: string) => {
       this.searchTerm = newValue;
       console.log("HERE" +this.searchTerm);
     });

       
  }

 
}
```

IMPORTANT: First I wanted to see if just one value from search is passed corectly

Comment: It seems to work correctly?

Comment: what are your expectation and the observed result? by giving a try to your link, it works as expected for me.

Comment: Great that you've added a working stackblitz :) Consider to add your code also to your question, so we can have a quick look without leaving SO ;) and your stackblitz seems to be working

Comment: I updated with my code. I want to show the data from the input in another page/component. I think I need to store the data in a localstorage or smth to get it there, but I don't know exactly how

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).